# Syntactic sugar doesn't work in metatable declaration in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm trying to add indexing to strings like in Python. This works:

```
getmetatable('').__index = function(str, i) return string.sub(str, i, i) end

str1 = 'hello'    
print(str1[1])
```

This doesn't:

```
getmetatable('').__index = function(str, i) return str:sub(i, i) end
```

Gives out the following error:

```
lua: test.lua:1: C stack overflow
stack traceback:
    test.lua:1: in function '__index'
    test.lua:1: in function '__index'
    ...
    test.lua:1: in function '__index'
    test.lua:4: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

Is there some sort of loop happening? Why?

Comment: `getmetatable('').__index = function(str, i) return string[i] or str:sub(i, i) end`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `str:method` shortcut works via `__index`.  By re-defining `__index`, you break that.

Since 5.2 or 5.3, Lua defines a metatable for strings, roughly like

```
debug.setmetatable( "", { __index = string } )
```

which permits writing `("foo"):sub( i, j )`.

---

Now you come along and say

```
getmetatable('').__index = function(str, i) return str:sub(i, i) end
```

so if you say `("foo")[2]`, that calls `__index( "foo", 2 )`, and inside that this causes the lookup `("foo")["sub"]` (in `str:sub(i, i)`).  This calls `__index( "foo", "sub" )`, and inside that this causes the lookup `("foo")["sub"]` (in `str:sub(i, i)`).  This calls `__index( "foo", "sub" )`, and…

…and the stack overflows, because you lookup `("foo")["sub"]` forever.

---

Re-defining `__index` in the way that you did means that you can no longer use that shortcut, which means you either have to spell out `string.method` instead of `str:method` ***everywhere** in your code, library code that you use, …* – or you keep it compatible.

Character-indexing only makes sense for numbers, so you can get both by saying

```
getmetatable( "" ).__index = function( str, k )
    if type( k ) ~= "number" then  return string[k]  end -- lookup in string.*
    return str:sub( k, k )
end
```

This will only call `string.sub` for a numeric index.  Method names are strings, so they will still be looked up in `string`.